# How to solve dataframes inside the list

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a problem of list with 9 rows and with ever row there is a dataframe of (36,6).
I want to append the data inside the dataframe and make it to 1 data frame with all the values and columns.
Like- i need a dataframe with 36*9 rows and 6 columns.

How to approach this in python!.

Any help would be great.

[This is what my list is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkS1W.png)

this is happening when I am performing for loop

Answer (score 1):

If each element in the list is a data frame, you should probably look for concatenation of your dataframe.

Suppose your list is `mylist`, then this should do the trick:

```
pandas.concat(mylist)
```